# Google Cloud Messaging Bitcode, linker command failed

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to build my app for IOS device, but receive the error:

```
d: '/PathToApp/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCloudMessaging.a(GGLContext+CloudMessaging.o)' 
does not contain bitcode. 
You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), 
obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. 
for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Clearly it states that Google Cloud Messaging does not contain bitcode. Turning off bitcode for both my app project and the 'Pods' project does successfully Build my application, but of course I want to follow Apple standards and have it enabled. Any way to solve this? Just wait for google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've marked this as an issue on GitHub, they said that it will be added in the next release.

https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/91

So, yes, We do have to wait for Google or any other experienced developer to release a bitcode version of Google Cloud Messaging.